# How to make containters get IP addresses from LAN and not from the bridge in netplan

Tags: netplan

Given the following:

Router <-----> Server [with multiple LXD containers]

How does one configure netplan so that:

- All LXD containers use Router's DHCP for IP addresses [i.e. bridge acts like a dumb switch]
- Server uses Router's DHCP for IP address [router allocates static IP of 192.168.1.64]

This:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    npbr0:
      interfaces:
        - enp0s31f6
      dhcp4: yes
```

is close except:

- LXD containers use bridge's DHCP and not Routers
- Server gets IP from the bridge

[Here](https://blog.simos.info/how-to-make-your-lxd-containers-get-ip-addresses-from-your-lan-using-a-bridge/) is how it used to be done under Network Manager

Comment: The directions you link to for setting this up with Network Manager look correct, and the netplan config you've provided for setting up the bridge on the host looks correct.  After setting up the bridge, did you follow the rest of the instructions regarding configuring the lxd profile?  You say "lxd containers use bridge's DHCP and not router's", but if lxd is configured correctly it is not providing a dhcp server on the bridge.

Comment: @slangasek - thanks I think I figured it out - they are mostly correct.  I found the solution on Archlinux -  `ip addr add dev npbr0 192.168.1.64/24` and a restart - which fixed things for me.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get it working, but this shows that you're setting a static IP address when you said your goal was to configure one with DHCP from the router.  Maybe you need to look at why the router is not assigning an IP?  If you decide to just use a statically configured IP on the bridge, you can do that through netplan using `addresses:`.

Comment: @slangasek, thanks again for the advise.  I found the solution was to match on  macaddress and then add that mac address to the bridge as well using  `macaddress:`

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to use the following config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      match:
        macaddress: 70:...
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces:
        - eth0
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      macaddress: 70:...
```

And then I could assign a static IP in my router which worked.

Comment: Looks good! Note that you should not have to use the mac address in a `match:` rule on the physical interface, it should work without, letting you save some duplication in the config.